# Slim4 through openapi-generator deployment problems

Tags: php, openapi-generator, slim-4

I've been working on this for several days now and I'm at the point of pulling my hair out.

**Goal:** to deploy Slim4 on my LAMP server within a specific subdirectory and accessible via a simple URL.

**Structure:**
There are several instances of my web app on the server and the setup should be replicated for all of them; the structure is straight forward:

/var/www/company1.com/app

- this "app" folder contains the main index.php of the website, as well as other various folders. Eg. /var/www/company1.com/app/index.php => https://company.com/index.php
- there is a folder called "api" within which I want to load Slim4. I don't really mind how this folder is structured and how deep it goes. I'm working on basis that this is where the composer file goes.
- the end result should be that the customer can access the api by calling https://company1.com/api

I'm using the openapi-generator and the Pet Store yaml file.
Running:

`openapi-generator-cli generate -i petstore.yaml -g php-slim4 -o /var/www/company1/api/`

I've then run `composer install` and setup the `config.inc.php` file as described in the instructions.

However when I navigate to http://company1.com/api I am greeted with the same issue every time:

`404 Not Found Type: Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException Code: 404 Message: Not found. File: /var/www/company1.com/app/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php Line: 91 Trace: #0 /var/www/company1.com/app/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(58): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting() #1 /var/www/company1.com/app/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(147): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process()`

it goes on...!

I can't figure this problem out.
This issue seems to be quite common as there are a lot of posts about it, so I'm convinced I've missed something very simple.

I have tried the following:

1. Setting the base path
   `$app->setBasePath("/api");`
2. Creating a /public/ folder and moving the index.php file there, then creating two different .htaccess files, based on these instructions:
   https://akrabat.com/running-slim-4-in-a-subdirectory/
3. using basepath as per its instructions
   https://github.com/selective-php/basepath

None of it seems to work! What am I doing wrong?

I have been able to successful load the Slim4 Skeleton application, however I want to use the openapi-generator so that I can have it automatically prepare all the php files based on my openapi yaml spec.

Any thoughts on tips would be greatly appreciated!